# service in kubernetes does not pass through all the headers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I have a following service in open shift

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: _api_minio
      service: "http://minio-svc:9000"
      prefix: /api/minio/
      rewrite: /
      bypass_auth: true
      host: xxxx
      add_response_headers:
        Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
        X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  creationTimestamp: '2020-01-09T15:10:34Z'
  labels:
    platform: xxx
  name: minio
  namespace: xxx
  resourceVersion: 'xxxxx'
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/services/minio
  uid: 2f7619a0-32f2-11ea-9dcc-xxxxxxxx
spec:
  clusterIP:xxxxx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

So this is a service which proxy the external request to internal minio which our object storage but as soon as I try to reach a url to the object I get:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

which seems that the above service does not pass through all the headers sent from browser.
Can anyone shed light on how I can pass through all headers coming in to the service to the internal service which is minio in this case?

Comment: Are you using ambassador? Maybe ambassador is not passing header.

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Yes I am using ambassador so how can I make ambassadors to pass the headers? I know very little about ambassadors

Answer (score 1):

In it's most basic configuration, Ambassador routes based off the incoming `prefix` of the request. Currently, you have Ambassador configured to route requests with `prefix: /api/minio/` to the service named `minio-svc` over port `9000` with `prefix: /`.

With this configuration, a request to `http(s)://{{IP}}/api/minio/` will correctly hit the `minio-svc` with the prefix rewritten to `/`. However, if you inspect the network logs, you will see that when minio receives a request with `prefix: /` it issues a 307 redirect to `/minio/` which is not a registered route in Ambassador which is why you see the failure.

The fix for this is to edit you `Mapping` to route based off the `prefix: /minio/` and not rewrite that prefix when sending the request downstream:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: _api_minio
      service: "http://minio-svc:9000"
      prefix: /minio/
      rewrite: ""
      bypass_auth: true
      host: xxxx
      add_response_headers:
        Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
        X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
  creationTimestamp: '2020-01-09T15:10:34Z'
  labels:
    platform: xxx
  name: minio
  namespace: xxx
  resourceVersion: 'xxxxx'
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/services/minio
  uid: 2f7619a0-32f2-11ea-9dcc-xxxxxxxx
spec:
  clusterIP:xxxxx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Now a request to `http(s)://{{IP}}/minio/` will be sent to the service `minio-svc` on port `9000` with `prefix: /minio/` which should resolve.

When debugging these kind of larger, GUI application behind a reverse proxy it is very useful to check the network logs of your browser to see if there are resource requests that are failing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I get all access to this bucket has been disabled I am not sure if it is any better. I am sure the bucket exists because with direct route to it I am able  to download the object

Comment: Here is another similar case when I use ambasador to create bucket: Cannot create bucket with name test-bucket-new-b3-hamed with error: AllAccessDisabled - All access to this bucket has been disabled. in us-east-1
{ code: 400,
  response:
   'Cannot create bucket with name test-bucket-new-b3-hamed with error: AllAccessDisabled - All access to this bucket has been disabled. in us-east-1' }

Answer (score 0):

Ambassador should not be stripping any headers from the request so I doubt that is the issue. You can test this by creating a `Mapping` that just points to a service that echos the headers it is receiving. The below can accomplish that using httpbin.org

```
---
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v1
kind: Mapping
metadata:
  name: httpbin
spec:
  prefix: /httpbin/
  service: httpbin.org
```

Now send a request to `http(s)://{{LOAD_BALANCER_IP}}/httpbin/headers` and it will respond with all of the headers it received from the request. You should see every header you sent plus a couple of more.

Without knowing more about the service you are hitting and the headers it is expecting it is hard to say exactly what is going wrong here so I would start with verifying it is an issue with headers being dropped.

Comment: But when I use direct route without using ambasador then everything works

Comment: So if I copy and paste the code you posted will I be able to check the headers? in  httpbin.org?

Comment: Sorry I actually had time to look at this today. The issue is with your `Mapping`. You have your proxy routing traffic to minio with `prefix: /api/minio`. Minio, however, is sending subsequent requests with the prefix `/minio/` which means, that while the first request is going through fine, all of the extra resource requests minio is sending are failing since the do not match a route in you proxy. Try changing your `Mapping` to have `prefix: /minio/` and `rewrite: ""` your proxy is routing requests with `prefix: /minio/`. Will post this as an answer for formatting as well